# Where to find old subfolders after redirecting URL (provided by host)?

Tags: url, redirect, dns, subdirectory

I am asking this question on behalf of some fellow classmates so, I apologize if I don't have all the details. I think it has to be a fairly simple answer, tho...

Anywho, several students who got their domain name from their host have since redirected said domain name's to sites like Squarespace, ProSite, etc. and now they can't access their old subfolders. For example, now that name.com redirects to their Squarespace site, they can no longer access the subfolder that used to be positioned at name.com/project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have had a heck of a time searching as everything I find is something about redirecting domains to subfolders or some such thing.

THANKS!

Comment: I guess we’d need to know *how* they are redirecting (e.g. the content of the `.htaccess`).

Answer (score 0):

How and for that URLs HTTP redirection happens is basically completely up to the web server and how it's configured.

Popular choices are configuring the server to redirect everything under a particular URL (probably what the servers in question have been configured to do), or redirecting only a specific URL while continuing to allow access to other URLs that happen to begin with the same prefix. Anything else you can think of configuring (typically, based on a regular expression match), is also possible.

So it all depends how the redirect was configured on the server and why it was done that way. There's often a good reason to redirect every URL that begins with a particular prefix, but a configuration that does this but makes an exception for a given subdirectory is certainly possible.